# Upload Quarkus dependency to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, quarkus

I have a Java based projects using Quarkus. However, the Jenkins pipeline does not support Maven 3.6.3 to build the project which is a Quarkus requirement.

Now, I need to move the Quarkus dependency (which are contained into the pom.xml file) to Sonatype Nexus and remove them from the pom.xml file so that the Jenkins pipeline build the project but takes the Quarkus libraries from Nexus already compiled.

So I take a look at the pom.xml file looking for the .jar files to upload to Nexus but there is a lot stuff here:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And if I open the folder 'External libraries' from IntelliJ I can find a lot of dependencies too:

[image]

So, my final question is how can I simply upload Quarkus to Nexus with just one simple archive? (jar, war, ear..)

Comment: What do you mean by "the Jenkins pipeline does not support Maven 3.6.3 to build the project which is a Quarkus requirement."? What stops you from using Maven 3.6.3?

Comment: @JFabianMeier the pipeline is an enterprise installation and they told me they cannot upgrade maven. So, I am forced to used the version 3.5.

Comment: What is the reason for not updating? What is an enterprise installation? Apart from that if you really forced to use old software then you can't do quarkus...

Comment: @khmarbaise does not matter why they cannot upgrade. Please consider this as a constrain of the problem. I can only use mvn 3.5 on Jenkins.

Comment: For someone searching a solution for this question. There is a tool called maven-wrapper, with this tool you can embed any maven version in your code and use it on the pipeline. More information at https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try building your app in a [maven docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/) for the pipeline.